# How to use PreparedStatement with foreign key

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working in a project of employees Attendance in Java (using NetBeans), I have created two tables, one for employee's data and the other to check the attendance.

Now I want to link the primary key of the first table to the second table but I do not know how. For example if you want to check the attendance it will show you the ID of the employee and when (time in / time out).

What I have tried:

This is the first table:

```sql
create table employee (
    empID int primary key auto_increment,
    fName varchar(100),
    civilId int,
    mobile int
);
```

The second table:

```sql
create table employeeAttendance (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    empID int not null,
    timeIn time,
    timeOut time,
    daay date,

    constraint emp_fk foreign key (empID) references employee (empID)
);
```

and in Java I did that but could not complete it :

```
String sql="insert into employeeAttendance(empID,timeIn,daay)values(?,?,?)";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

pstmt.setString(1,.getText());
pstmt.setString(2,timeLabel.getText());
pstmt.setString(3,dateLabel.getText());
```

Comment: "could not complete it" ? What went wrong?

Comment: @khelwood I do not know what to write here pstmt.setString(1,.getText());

Comment: error code pstmt.setString(1,.getText());

Comment: @AxelH, I don't think it is auto-increment.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava the query is in the question  `...empID int primary key 
auto_increment...` **EDIT : my bad, different table !**

Comment: @AxelH, I think you are referring wrong table. Check employeeAttendance table

Comment: You need to get the `employee.empID` value. We can't help with this since we don't know what you already have. Seems you are using a GUI to get the value `time` and `date`. What about the employee ? If you are using a list of existing employee, you should be able to get the instance with there ID but that's not answerable since we don't know what you have.

Comment: @AxelH thanks ,about the employee , I am not using a list , all what I've done is adding jTextFields and link it to the database

Comment: So you enter the name of the employe ? Please [edit] the question with that information, this is the only way we can help you to get that first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You did almost everything right in terms of functionality.

Please don't use text fields for integer and date if you can avoid it. Every major UI Framework has fields for this special types, so use them!

However, you should use the correct setter method of `PreparedStatement`. If your column is an int you should use `ps.setInt`, if you have a time/timestamp/date column you should use `ps.setDate`.

So your Java code would look like this

```
SimpleDateFormatter sdf = new SimpleDateFormatter("dd.MM.yyyy");
java.util.Date jtimeIn = sdf.parse(timeLabel.getText());
java.sql.Date stimeOut = new java.sql.Date(jdate.getTime()); //This part is important, jdbc uses java.sql.Dates!

java.util.Date jdaay = sdf.parse(dateLabel.getText());
java.sql.Date sdaay = new java.sql.Date(jdaay.getTime()); //This part is important, jdbc uses java.sql.Dates!

String sql="insert into employeeAttendance(empID,timeIn,daay)values(?,?,?)";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

pstmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(empIDAsText));
pstmt.setDate(2,stimeOut);
pstmt.setString(3,sdaay);
```

Comment: thank you but it shows me an error ! it says java.lang.unsupportedOperationException:not supported yet

Comment: @AhmadAlharbi can you please post the entire exception and where it occurs.

Comment: I think I know how to solve it , but firstly can you please explain what does " (empIDAsText) " mean ?

Comment: @AhmadAlharbi i assumed that you use your input for empID  also as text but you didn't include it in your code snippet, so i improvized and added that. Also if you have your problem solved please add a comment or edit to the end of your question, so other people can see the solution.

Comment: This is not correct. JDBC drivers should support a number of conversions between Java types and target JDBC/SQL types. This includes the conversion from a `java.lang.String` to a SQL `INTEGER`, and to `DATE`, etc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i only recommend you to read the documentation of the preparestatement object. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html. If you use standard preparestatements you need to use them accordingly. And last of all, it is NOT RECOMMENDED and NOT INTENDED to set an Integer with a String not on Java side nor on SQL side. You gotta cast or format anything you have before using them.

Comment: @LeventDag I'm a member of the JDBC Expert Group and an implementer of a JDBC driver. I think I'm pretty much up to speed on how JDBC works. Although I agree that it is better to use specific types, using `setString` instead of `setInt` should work and the driver or database should convert this for you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i do not doubt your knowledge, however it may wary with the driver in use. For example as an user of postgresql i know that their driver, does not support such an action. I am trying to point out a coding style that doesnt just work for one specific project, rather for each and every one. And frankly its just bad coding style, ignoring the typesafety of java.